# How to retrieve USB device interface GUID?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, usb

To get the GUID for a HID device, I know I can do this:

```
GUID myHidGuid;
memset(&myHidGuid, 0, sizeof(GUID)); //allocate
HidD_GetHidGuid(&myHidGuid); //define the HID GUID
```

Is there a function similar to HidD_GetHidGuid() that will give me the GUID for other device classes?

I am trying to determine if a USB wireless network adaptor is attached. I believe I want GUID_DEVINTERFACE_NET but I don't know how to retrieve it.

Comment: SetupDiCreateDeviceInfoList + SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff541247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @HansPassant can you explain a little more? it read to me that the way you use that is by first giving the GUID to SetupDiCreateDeviceInfoList() which puts me right back where I started...

Comment: You select the type of device you want to enumerate, it is a "class guid".  Like GUID_DEVINTERFACE_NET

Comment: @HansPassant I already know that I want to enumerate the type GUID_DEVINTERFACE_NET . I am asking if there exists a function which will set a variable to the value GUID_DEVINTERFACE_NET (without me explicitly referencing GUID_DEVINTERFACE_NET)

Comment: The reason I want to do it this way, is my program will be given an input, and based on that input it will return if either a specific HID device is attached, or if a specific network adaptor is attached.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you have something similar, these ClassGuids are decided by Microsoft the list is here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553426(v=vs.85).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553428(v=vs.85).aspx

A good example would be this [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14412/Enumerating-windows-device).

Comment: too bad! I have had to this :
  `if (USBtype == 1)
  {
   HidD_GetHidGuid(&myHidGuid); //define the HID GUID
  }
  else if (USBtype == 2)
  {
   myHidGuid = GUID_DEVINTERFACE_NET; //define the HID GUID
  }`

because of a linker error when I try to use GUID_DEVINTERFACE_HID. I wanted the cases to match :)

Thanks for the links!

Comment: post some code, and more details about the error, it sounds interesting

Comment: Just FYI, device **setup** classes are not necessarily the same thing as device **interface** classes, the links you posted are for device setup classes, [here's a list of device interface classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553412(v=vs.85).aspx). You might also find [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/setup-classes-versus-interface-classes) interesting Also it looks like you posted the same link twice.